Bash Script Fails to Send JSON Payload in cURL Request to ASP.NET Core Controller
Title:
Bash Script Fails to Send JSON Payload in cURL Request to ASP.NET Core Controller
Question:
I'm facing an issue where my bash script does not properly send a JSON payload to my ASP.NET Core controller method using cURL. The payload appears to be missing or not formatted correctly when it reaches the server. However, when I include the parameter directly in the URL, it works fine.
Here is my bash script:
#!/bin/bash

# Argument
CATEGORY_NAME=$1

# JSON payload
JSON_PAYLOAD="{\"name\":\"$CATEGORY_NAME\"}"

# Debug: Print the JSON payload to verify its correctness
echo "JSON Payload: $JSON_PAYLOAD"

# Send POST request with JSON payload
curl -X POST "https://localhost:7225/add_category" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d "$JSON_PAYLOAD"

And here is the corresponding ASP.NET Core controller method:
[HttpPost("add_category")]
public IActionResult AddCategory([FromBody] CategoryRequest request)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Name))
    {
        return BadRequest("Category name is required.");
    }

    using (var conn = GetConnection())
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("add_category", conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("p_name", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar) { Value = request.Name });
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    return Ok("Category added Successfully");
}

public class CategoryRequest
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

When I run the script, the request.Name in the controller method is null. However, if I use the following curl command directly, it works:
curl -X POST "https://localhost:7225/add_category?name=YourCategoryName" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json"

What I have tried:

Debugging the JSON payload in the bash script to ensure it is correctly formatted.
Ensuring the Content-Type header is set to application/json.
Verifying that the server can handle JSON payloads correctly.

What I am looking for:
I need help to understand why the JSON payload is not being sent correctly from my bash script and how to resolve this issue. Any suggestions or corrections to my script or server-side code would be greatly appreciated.

A quick glance at the ASP.NET docs makes it look like the default Parameter binding is fromURI and what you want is fromBody.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api
